# Failed comunication between Logstash and RabbitMQ (both in one separate MS Azure Virtual machine)

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, azure-virtual-machine

I have created two service in Azure "**RabbitMQ**" and "**ELK**" (both in one separate *MS Azure Virtual machine*).

My MVC ASP.net application write in RabbitMQ (I have to configure an endpoint (inbound security rule) RabbitMQ (TCP/5672) and I can see in RabbitMQ webadmin my queue. 
Logstash (in vm ELK) write correct index for "logstash-*" collect data from apache log.

I think I missing some endpoint configuration in vm. But I don't know what. Or I have put some incorrect configuration my logstash config /opt/bitnami/logstash/conf/logstash.conf :

---

```
input
{
rabbitmq {
type => "myqueuelog"
host => "x.x.x.x" # ip address to vm rabbitmq
port => 5672
vhost => "myvhost"
queue => "myqueuelog"
auto_delete => false
codec => "plain"
exclusive => false
heartbeat => 30
durable => true
password => "mypass"
user => "user"
}
rabbitmq {
type => "myqueueerror"
host => "x.x.x.x" # ip address to vm rabbitmq
port => 5672
vhost => "myvhost"
queue => "myqueueerror"
auto_delete => false
codec => "plain"
exclusive => false
heartbeat => 30
durable => true
password => "mypass"
user => "user"
}
beats
{
ssl => false
host => "0.0.0.0"
port => 5044
}
gelf
{
host => "0.0.0.0"
port => 12201
}
http
{
ssl => false
host => "0.0.0.0"
port => 8888
}
tcp
{
mode => "server"
host => "0.0.0.0"

    mode => "server"
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 5010
}
udp
{
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 5000
}
}

filter {
if [type] == "myqueuelog" {
# split the message field (in json format)
json {
source => "message" # where is the json
}
}
if [type] == "myqueueerror" {
# split the message field (in json format)
json {
source => "message" # where is the json
}
}
}

output
{

if [type] == "myqueuelog" {
        elasticsearch
        {
            codec => "json"
            hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
            document_id => "%{logstash_checksum}"
            index => "myqueuelog-%{+YYYY}"
           # protocol => "http"
            manage_template => false
        }
    }
if [type] == "myqueueerror" {
elasticsearch
{
codec => "json"
hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
document_id => "%{logstash_checksum}"
index => "myqueueerror-%{+YYYY}"
# protocol => "http"
manage_template => false
}
}

}
```

---

and I have found a log error in LOGSTASH:

```
[ERROR][logstash.pipeline] Error registering plugin {:plugin=>"false, host=>\"0.0.0.0\", port=>8888, id=>\"ccfb769a49le707254a6d272716b8aa18d57dfec-18\", enable_metric=>true, codec=>\"plain_0045le0e-9c30-4d95-b400-97843e19022e\", enable_metric=>true, charset=>\"UTF-8\">, threads=>4, verify_mode=>\"none\", additional_codecs=>{\"application/json\"=>\"json"}, response_headers=>{\"Content-Type\"text/plain\"}>, :error=>"Address already in use - bind - Address already in use"}
[ERROR][logstash.agent] Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>#, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPServer.java:118:in 'initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyIO.java:871 ...etc...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error states `Address already in use - bind - Address already in use` so you must have something running on port 8888

Comment: Yes, one of the configuration problem is this. I have change 2 port number of two plugin elk and now works. Thanks

Comment: Good you figured it out